# How can migrate all databases from one server to another server in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to migrate my all databases from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2014. Is there any way to do all in one short instead of one by one?

Comment: You can stop the serer, and copy the SQL data files, (ldf and MDF) to new server, and then use attach option

Comment: Suppose thousand of Databases are there?

Comment: You need not do it manually, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-attach-db-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do in-place upgrade in the same server, instead of migration, if possible. It will one-shot operation.

You can do side by side migration, by taking backup in source environment(MSSQL 2012) and restore databases in target environment(MSSQL 2014).

This is a very important operation and many things have to be planned. You have to have migration plan for this.

You can use upgrade advisor tool for this. It will tell you whether everything is fine on your instance for initial analysis: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn236457(v=sql.120).aspx

Also, read below articles.

https://thomaslarock.com/2014/06/upgrading-to-sql-server-2014-a-dozen-things-to-check/

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2013/12/14/what-to-consider-when-creating-sql-server-database-migration-plan/

There are lots of guides available online. Just search internet. you will find many guides.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 ways:

1.Create a backup of your database and restore it in new server.From Management Studio you can Right-click on your database then select Tasks -> Back up.

2.Generate script, create the database in the new server and run the script.From Management Studio you can Right-click on your database then select Tasks -> Generate Scripts.

Comment: But I want all databases , not to one by one.